# How to limit a table to only 50 rows?

Tags: python, database, nosql, griddb

I am not talking about getting data from a table and limiting the output to only 50 rows. I want to place
a restriction on a database table in such a way that if a new row is added, it throws an error. The table
can be updated or rows deleted, but it cannot have more than 50 rows in total. I don't know if this
makes sense but I want to do this with GridDB on my Ubuntu machine. Thanks for your help!

Comment: What `python` doing here>?